# Pignose Calendar - Buttons + Date range on 2 months

Tags: jquery, calendar

Here is my code :

```
$('.calendar').pignoseCalendar({
    lang:'fr',
    modal:true,
    multiple:true,
    buttons:true,
    initialize: false,
    apply: function(date, context) {
         //Do something with dates
    }
});
```

All is good except when i try to select a date range over 2 months (ex: 2019-11-25 => 2019-12-02)
When i do that the calendar buttons don't trigger anything (neither cancel nor ok), it get stuck until i select range only on one month.

Is there a trick to do that or i need to deal with "next" event ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

Just use id selector $('#itemID').pignoseCalendar for each calendar instead of one declaration selected by class like i did.
It work like a charm this way.